# Select result from two tables (Mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables one is **employee_job** table and another is **employee_exit** table which have the mapping data of **employee_id**.

**employee_job** table

```
id |  employee_id | date_of_joining | date_of_rehire
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 2015-01-01      | 2015-07-01
2  | 2            | 2014-02-01      | 2014-12-01
```

**employee_exit** table

```
id |  employee_id | date_of_termination | date_of_rehire
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 2015-02-15          | 2015-03-01
2  | 1            | 2015-03-31          | 2015-05-01
3  | 1            | 2015-05-31          | 2015-07-01 
4  | 2            | 2014-06-12          | 2014-07-01 
5  | 2            | 2014-10-31          | 2014-12-01
6  | 2            | 2015-02-30          | (NULL)
```

Only latest **date_of_rehire** will come in **employee_job** table when only employee is rehired. If it is **terminated** after rehire then previously **date_of_rehire** will exists in **employee_job** table.

As result i need the following output:-

```
employee_id  |  date_of_hire | date_of_termination
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1            | 2015-01-01    | 2015-02-15 
1            | 2015-03-01    | 2015-03-31
1            | 2015-05-01    | 2015-05-31
1            | 2015-07-01    | (NULL) 
2            | 2014-02-01    | 2014-06-12 
2            | 2014-07-01    | 2014-10-31
2            | 2014-12-01    | 2015-02-30
```

If employee is hired multiple times with employer then it's first hiring period between **date_of_joining** to **date_of_termination** and then after **date_of_rehire** to **date_of_termination**.

If employee is hired only one time then it's hiring period between **date_of_joining** to **date_of_termination**.

Comment: I am using Mysql as database.

Comment: I did not really understand your question, but here is a link to learn about joins. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you have your db layed out in this fashion? It would be so much easier to have a table with the employee id, the start date and the end date as fields. As you have it you are storing the time that an employee is not employed in one table and then two seperate start dates in another

Comment: @Anton - This is old designed , i can't change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this task perspective there is no difference between `date_of_joining` and `date_of_rehire` across both tables, so we just need to `Union` them all and supplement with the nearest `date_of_termination`:

```
Select
  Hire.employee_id,
  Hire.date_of_hire,
  (
    Select Min(date_of_termination)
    From employee_exit
    Where employee_exit.employee_id = Hire.employee_id
      AND employee_exit.date_of_termination > Hire.date_of_hire
  ) As date_of_termination
From (
    Select       employee_id, date_of_joining As date_of_hire From employee_job
  /*Optional, in case employee_job has date_of_rehire not in employee_exit     */
  /*Union Select employee_id, date_of_rehire                  From employee_job*/
    Union Select employee_id, date_of_rehire                  From employee_exit
  ) Hire
Order By
  Hire.employee_id,
  Hire.date_of_hire
```

There can be an ambiguous result if any of the dates are not recorded accurately in the database.

Comment: I have updated the question , please see it again.. only latest date_of_rehire exists in the employee_job table so you can't use it.

Comment: @RobinSaxena That's fine. Please note I am combining `date_of_hire` from both tables.

Comment: Thanks for reply and we can remove date_of_rehire union from employee_job table

Answer (score 0):

My primary answer would be to rework your database so that you dont have to do a complex query for what should be a fairly straight forward operation. If that is not an option then below I have given a quick answer. There may be an isse but it should put you on the right track

I would use a Union to combine the results of the two queries you want(first term of employment and then all other terms of employment):

```
    (SELECT employee_job.employee_id, employee_job.date_of_joining as date_of_hire, employee_exit.date_of_termination 
     FROM employee_job       
     JOIN employee_exit
     ON employee_job.employee_id = employee_exit.employee_id
     UNION
     SELECT employee_job.employee_id, employee_exit.date_of_rehire as date of hire, employee_exit.date of termination 
    FROM employee_job       
     JOIN employee_exit
     ON employee_job.id = employee_exit.id)
     ORDER BY employee.id
```

This may give you duplicates, if so then a carefully placed where clause is needed :D